# A simple webserver in C++ using asio and form post from safari appears not to work

Tags: html, c++, http, post, boost-asio

Safari is sending http form post and data in separate ip packets. So I test for the last three chars and perform another async_read_some() to get the form data. Solution is in the answer.

I'm writing a simple webserver in C++ using boost asio and coroutines. This is to get some deeper understanding of both C++ and http. I'm making a simple html post form and can enter first- and lastname in the form, submit the form and display the data.

It works fine in firefox and chrome on mac/win10, and on egde on win10. But submitting the same form on safari doesn't seem to post the data.

This is the form in firefox after I wrote Ål (eel) and Sæl (seal):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Tabula content server</title><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post">
    Fornavn:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Efternavn:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="OK">
  </form>
  <br>firstname=Ål&lastname=Sæl&name=OK
</body>
</html>
```

I'm copying the data sent from the browser into a char buffer and this is the output of that buffer from the post form, using firefox.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1967
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: da,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:1967/
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 43

firstname=%C3%85l&lastname=S%C3%A6l&name=OK
```

When I submit the same post form in safari the last part of the output is

```
: da-dk Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

This is the form post sent to the server:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1967
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://localhost:1967
Content-Length: 35
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56
Referer: http://localhost:1967/
Accept-Language: da-dk
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

I parse the content-length and then extract the last part of the buffer to get the data transmitted. But safari seems to handle this form post different. I looked at [Form submit not posting Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174386/form-submit-not-posting-safari) and added name="name" to input type="submit". But no change.

This is the part that receives the form post. Complete project at https://github.com/kometen/Tabula.

```
void do_read(tcp::socket& tcp_socket, yield_context yield) {
    size_t length = tcp_socket.async_read_some(buffer(bytes), yield);
    // POST
    if (bytes[0] == 'P' && bytes[2] == 'S' && bytes[4] == ' ' && bytes[5] == '/') {
        for (int j = 0; j < BUFSIZE || bytes[j] == '\0'; ++j) {
            // If Content-Length:
            if (bytes[j] == 'C' && bytes[j+8] == 'L' && bytes[j+14] == ':') {
                for (int k = (j + 16);; ++k) {
                    if (bytes[k] == '\r' || bytes[k] == '\0') {
                        break;
                    }
                    cls.push_back(bytes[k]);
                }
                cl = (unsigned int) stoul(cls);
            }
        }
    }
    // Output to console
    cout << "do_read() START, size: " << length << ", input: " << endl << endl << bytes << endl << endl << "do_read() END" << endl;

    // Append to form returned to browser
    for (auto j = (length - cl); j < length; ++j) {
        postdata.append(1, bytes[j]);
    }

    spawn(ioservice, [&] (yield_context yield) { do_write(tcp_socket, yield); });
}

void do_write(tcp::socket& tcp_socket, yield_context yield) {
    Content content;
    content.setPostdata(postdata);
    string data = content.getContent();
    async_write(tcp_socket, buffer(data), yield);
    tcp_socket.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
}

void do_accept(yield_context yield) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        tcp::socket *tcp_socket = new tcp::socket {ioservice};
        tcp_acceptor.async_accept(*tcp_socket, yield);
        spawn(ioservice, [&] (yield_context yield) { do_read(*tcp_socket, yield); });
    }
}

int main() {
    tcp_acceptor.listen();
    spawn(ioservice, do_accept);
    ioservice.run();
    return 0;
}
```

regards
Claus

Comment: I just tried a simple [test](http://pastebin.com/3Vp2zw09) using php's built-in server on safari 8.0.8 and I can't replicate this using the form you provided, it works as expected. Post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your c++ code.

Comment: Also I doubt it'll change anything but on the off chance that Safari 9.0 is being really pedantic you should delete `action="" ` as it isn't valid html (if the `action` attribute is specified it **must** have a valid non-empty URL).

Comment: I have cloned the git-repo on a raspberry pi with FreeBSD 10.2 stable, using boost ver. 1.55.00 and on my mac it's boost ver. 1.59.00. It works on the R-PI. I'll do a tcpdump. It might be about boost library versions.

Comment: Is there a chance that POST data from Safari just don't fit in some kind of buffer, or just have not been received yet? The `Content-Length` suggests that 35 bytes of POST data *is* sent.

Comment: Yes, the content-length does indicate it. Maby it's related to different boost versions. Works using boost ver. 1.55.00.

Comment: Please note that there's absolutely no guarantee that you receive all data sent by the browser in one `read()`. In theory, it could be even split in one-byte chunks.

Comment: Using wireshark I see the the data is sent in the next package so I'm closing the async_read_some() too soon. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I couldn't get it to work in safari is because it sends the http post form header and data in separate ip packets. So I read the last three chars if it's a post form and does a second async_read_some(). It may not be the correct way to write this, but I'm learning along the way.

This checks if the form data comes in a separate ip packet:

```
// If form data is arriving in a separate ip packet.
if (is_post && bytes[length] == '\0' && bytes[length-1] == '\n' && bytes[length-2] == '\r') {
    size_t additional_length = tcp_socket.async_read_some(buffer(additional_bytes), yield);
    // Move back and overwrite delimiter and copy.
    --length;
    for (auto i = 0; i < additional_length; ++i) {
        bytes[++length] = additional_bytes[i];
    }
    bytes[++length] = '\0';
}

for (auto j = (length - cl); j < length; ++j) {
    postdata.append(1, bytes[j]);
}
```

regards
Claus